# updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'

Tags: locate, updatedb

I go to use the updatedb command to update the index and I get

```
updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'
```

fyi The locate command is working, e.g.

```
$ locate Index.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml
durrantm.../durrantm$
```

How can I overcome this issue when trying to run updatedb?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to run the updatedb command as the super user. For example,

```
sudo updatedb
```

Comment: Once created, can the database be updated by a regular user (_e.g._ from `crontab`) without super-user privileges?

Comment: The update db creates the cache file in /var/cache/locate/locatedb, which is only writable by root. So regular user cannot run the command.

But it is possible to create a file in different location which is writable by a regular user. (But the problem is regular users cannot read the whole file system)

Comment: Even sudo didn't work in my case :/ @ManulaWaidyanatha

Answer (score 5):

If you lack time and want to locate a file,
you don't need to `sudo updatedb` in order to update cache.
Instead, you can use `locate -e filename` to skip cache.

Comment: If you don't have the ability to sudo or don't have mlocate installed, you can use this to find files in the folders where you have permission to look (substitute `file*.name` with any wildcard-capable filename that you're looking for):
`find / -iname "file*.name" -print 2>/dev/null`