# Sudo updatedb `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db' is locked due to faulty drive, how to resolve permanently?

Tags: arch-linux, locate

This 4.20.3 Arch system its BTRFS formatted `/` disk is without free space left. It turns out that mlocate is the cause:

```
# du -h --exclude=Volumes -- * 2>/dev/null | sort -hr | head -2
11G var
9.6G    var/lib/mlocate
```

The question [updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82985/updatedb-can-not-open-a-temporary-file-for-var-lib-mlocate-mlocate-db) accepted answer suggests to prepend `sudo`, though that doesn't change a thing:

```
# sudo updatedb
updatedb: `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db' is locked (probably by an earlier updatedb)
```

There seems to be a temporary file in /var/lib/mlocate that is eating up all disk space:

```
# ls -lh var/lib/mlocate/
-rw-r----- 1 root locate 1.1M Oct 21 00:00 mlocate.db
-rw------- 1 root root   9.6G Dec 30 19:46 mlocate.db.PRvfsw
```

Could the root cause be the `.timer` update job that is hanging?

```
# systemctl status updatedb.timer
* updatedb.timer - Daily locate database update
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/updatedb.timer; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-10-21 16:05:10 CEST; 2 months 9 days ago
  Trigger: n/a
```

Both `restart` and `stop` don't remove the temporary large .db file and `updatedb` still returns `locked`.

There seems to be an `updatedb` process still running:

```
# ps -ef | grep updatedb
root      3249     1 99 Oct22 ?        213573-14:47:11 /usr/bin/updatedb
```

I know I can kill this process. The root cause is most likely a faulty USB stick:

```
# ls /Volumes/RM_GUE__
ls: cannot access '/Volumes/RM_GUE__/'$'\001\020': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '/Volumes/RM_GUE__/)': Input/output error
```

Though the next time a USB stick becomes faulty, `/` will fill up again.

#### updatedb.conf

The `updatedb.conf` options don't bring me any useful filter option:

- by path: I can't guess the name that the partition will have after corruption
- by filesystem: In this case VFAT was corrupted (and read-only), though I can't look in to the future which file system will get corrupted.

How to resolve this issue neat and permanently, for example by limiting the duration that `updatedb.timer` may run and/or skipping disks which suffer input/output errors, or limit the file size `LimitFSIZE=` or even something better?

Comment: Last resort will be to completely disable the updatedb.timer, maybe "[write your own updatedb.service file WITH the needed section to use enable/disable and place it in /etc/systemd/check-documentation-where-to-put-it](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200479)"

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `mlocate` (see `man mlocate`) leads to `updatedb`, which in turn says

> The `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS`, `PRUNEFS`, `PRUNENAMES` and `PRUNEPATHS` variables, which are modified by some of the options, are documented in detail in `updatedb.conf`(5).

Reading the documentation for that (`man updatedb.conf`) and looking at the file `/etc/updatedb.conf` shows two possible options to satisfy your requirement:

> `PRUNEFS` A whitespace-separated list of file system types (as used in /etc/mtab)  which  should  not  be scanned  by  `updatedb`(8).   The  file system type matching is case-insensitive.
>
> `PRUNEPATHS` A whitespace-separated list of path names of directories which should not be scanned by `updatedb`(8).  Each path name must be exactly in the form in which the directory would be reported by `locate`(1).

If your USB sticks and other removable media are always mounted under `/Volumes` you could add that directory to your `PRUNEPATHS` setting in `/etc/updatedb.conf`. On my Debian system this would result in

```
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /var/lib/os-prober /Volumes"
```

Alternatively, if your USB sticks are always FAT or NTFS you could add those filesystem types to the set of exclusions specified by `PRUNEFS`.

Comment: I mount my rotating hard disk drives also under /Volumes, so PRUNEPATHS=/Volumes is not an option. The faulty filesystem in question is VFAT, though `PRUNEFS` would stop indexing `/boot` as well. No winner here. I'd wish to exclude devices that have been opened read-only: `/dev/sdc has been opened read-only`.

Comment: Goals have changed, so answer is no longer relevant